# Reload div with only javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript

With jQuery I can update the contents of a div I using `$.load()`. How can I update a div in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Make an ajax call, use `.innerHTML` to update element contents.

Comment: in javascript you have to write the function yourself to do the working of $.load .Just google AJAX and you will get how to

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by Julian H. Lam:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "address_for_div_content", true);
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return;
  document.getElementById('id_of_div')=req.responseText;
};
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) the documentation for XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 2):

I had radio inputs and wanted to reload them with the default checked values from the html; this worked for me:

```
const content = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript (not JQuery) solution : wrap your div in an iframe, give it an id myFrame, then refresh it from the child like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("myFrame").reload();
```

Comment: I guess *"wrap your div in an iframe"* actually means *"create a new page with just the `div`'s content and load it via an iframe"*