# Replace div using JQuery ajax, not replace contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's an example doc structure

```
<div>
    <div id="1" class="to-replace"></div>
    <div id="2" class="to-replace"></div>
    <div id="3" class="to-replace"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is replace `#1`, for example, with whatever I retrieve from the ajax call (I'm not using JSON because the request is extremely small and it didn't seem worth it. Plus, the site is mostly for my personal use). I know I can use JQuery `.load()` to replace the contents, but there must be some easy way to replace the whole thing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987135/reload-div-with-only-javascript-without-jquery/16987281#16987281

Comment: Are you coding in `HTML5`? **If you aren't**, your `id` attributes are invalid. [They must not begin with a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id).

Comment: @Ghillied I'm not, but it was just an example. I didn't actually name them 1, 2, 3. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get(url,function(data){
   $("#1").replaceWith(data);
});
```

where url is the url to whatever you want to get and data is the data that is returned

Answer (score 5):

You can use the replaceWith jquery function to replace an element:

```
    $("#1").replaceWith("bla");
```